# Div dentro de outra div quebrada

Tags: php, html

Como inserir uma div dentro de outra div sem que nenhuma delas faça a quebra de linha.

Quero fazer desse jeito pois estou em desenvolvimento de um website de clan e no index tem que ter o botão de login ou registro, eu fiz isso mas quando fui rodar o html ele fez a quebra de linha da 2a div.

```html
<div id="menubarwidget">
  <div id="register"><a href="?action=register">Registro</a></div>
  <div id="login"><a href="?action=login">Entrar</a></div>
  <!-- E se for o caso do $_COOKIE retornar um usuário já logado -->
  <div id="loggedin" style="display: <?php echo $logged_display; ?>"><span id="username"><?php echo $logged_in_user; ?></span></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode inserir uma classe, para manipular no css.

E vc pode definir que elas estejam dipostas **inline**, conforme o exemplo:

```css
.menu
{
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="menubarwidget">
  <div class="menu" id="register"><a href="?action=register">Registro</a></div>
  <div class="menu" id="login"><a href="?action=login">Entrar</a></div>
  <!-- E se for o caso do $_COOKIE retornar um usuário já logado -->
  <div id="loggedin" style="display: <?php echo $logged_display; ?>"><span id="username"><?php echo $logged_in_user; ?></span></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```css
.row {
 display: table;
 width: auto;
 border-spacing: 5px; /*cellspacing:poor IE support for  this*/
 margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
}

.form-group-col {
 float: left; /*fix for  buggy browsers*/
 display: table-column;
 margin: 0;
 width: auto;
 display: table-column-group;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group-col">
    Texto 01
  </div>
  <div class="form-group-col">
    Texto 02
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar o **float:left** no CSS do div register para evitar isso.

```css
#register { float:left; }
```

```html
<div id="menubarwidget">
  <div id="register"><a href="?action=register">Registro</a></div>
  <div id="login"><a href="?action=login">Entrar</a></div>
 </div>
```

De forma mais elaborada pode fazer como o Mayllon Baumer disse ou até usar um framework CSS para cuidar do Grid.

Answer (score 2):

Cada elemento no HTML possui uma propriedade `display`, no caso do `<div>` o `display` é definido como `block` por padrão. O `block` "diz" a cada elemento que o possui para sempre começar em uma nova linha, no caso do `<div>`(divisão) a propriedade faz jus ao seu nome.
Existem outros valores que você pode definir para `display`, um deles é o `inline`. Veja mais sobre a propriedade `display` [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/display)

No seu caso, por se tratar de um menu, faz mas sentido, ao invés de encapsular os links em um `<div>`, colocar dentro de uma estrutura de menu, própria para isto. O menu (`<ul>`) possui seus itens (`<li>`). Os `<li>` por padrão, também possuem o valor `block`, mas se tratando de semântica visual, faz mais sentido dizer que um `<li>` é `inline` do que um `<div>`.

Neste caso, uma vou deixar uma dica/exemplo de como poderia fazer isto:

```css
#menuBarWidget li {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="menuBarWidget">
    <ul>
        <li id="register">
            <a href="?action=register">Registro</a>
        </li>
        <li id="login">
            <a href="?action=login">Entrar</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="loggedin" style="display: <?php echo $logged_display; ?>">
        <span id="username"><?php echo $logged_in_user; ?></span>
    </div>
</div>
```